# geoNear exception: 'near' field must be point

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have run the following query successfully in the mongo shell:

```
db.runCommand({
    geoNear : "stores",
    near : { type : "Point", coordinates : [ -3.978, 50.777 ] },
    spherical : true,
    limit : 10
})
```

I am trying to convert this into a mongoose query for my node service  [as shown in the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.geoNear).

```
Store.geoNear(
    { type : "Point", coordinates : [-3.978, 50.777]}, 
    { spherical : true, limit : 10 }, 
    function (error, results, stats) {
    //do stuff with results here
});
```

This is returning the following error:

```
MongoError: exception: 'near' field must be point
```

My `Store` schema is defined like this:

```
var storeSchema = new Schema({
    // irrelevant fields...
    locations : [
        {
            address : {
                streetAddress : String,
                postalCode : String
            }
            coords : {
                type : [Number],
                index : '2dsphere'
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

There is only one 2dsphere index on the collection, and as I mentioned, it works through the shell, just not with mongoose.

**Edit:** Other things I've tried without success:

Falling back to using mongodb native driver (same error, so I suspect it's mongodb rather than mongoose causing the problem):

```
Store.collection.geoNear(
    { type : "Point", coordinates : [-3.978, 50.777]}, 
    { spherical : true, limit : 10 }, 
    function (error, results, stats) {
    //do stuff with results here
});
```

Falling back to using legacy coordinates instead of geopoints (both mongoose and native (same error)):

```
Store.geoNear(
    -3.978, 50.777, 
    { spherical : true, limit : 10 }, 
    function (error, results, stats) {
    //do stuff with results here
});
```

Using runCommand from mongoose (this errors differently, saying that `Store.db.command` is not a function - the correct way to call this from mongoose would be an acceptable answer):

```
Store.db.command({
    geoNear : "stores",
    near : { type : "Point", coordinates : [ -3.978, 50.777 ] },
    spherical : true,
    limit : 10
}, function(error, results){})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to work out how to fall back to use `runCommand` via the mongodb native driver:

```
Store.db.db.command({
    geoNear : "stores",
    near : { type : "Point", coordinates : [ -3.978, 50.777 ] },
    spherical : true,
    limit : 10
}, function(error, results){})
```